# MYSQL: foreign key error

Tags: mysql

I am getting some foreign key error while adding one. I have:

```
CREATE TABLE PRODUCT_1( PROD_ID NUMERIC(5) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  PROD_NAME CHAR(20), 
  PROD_DESC CHAR(20),  
  PROD_PRICE NUMERIC(20), 
  SIZE_ID NUMERIC(5) NOT NULL, 
  PROD_CAT_ID CHAR(5));


CREATE TABLE SIZE( 
  SIZE_ID NUMERIC(5) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
  SIZE_SMALL CHAR(2), 
  SIZE_MEDIUM CHAR(2), 
  SIZE_LARGE CHAR(2));
```

I am trying to add foreign key using:

alter table SIZE
add foreign key(SIZE_ID) references PRODUCT_1(SIZE_ID)

BUT I get the following errors:
ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table './mmmm/#sql-842_33e1.frm' (errno: 150)

However, If I go the other way round like:

alter table PRODUCT_1
add foreign key(SIZE_ID) references SIZE(SIZE_ID)

This works fine, I am unable to add any data to it where it gives me error like "cannot update child table".

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: `size_id` is neither the primary key nor a unique key in product_1. A foreign key can only reference those. You probably want to make (prod_id, size_id) the primary key in `product_1` and add a `prod_id` to the `size` table.

Answer (score 1):

That is correct.  SIZE_ID is a "foreign key" in PRODUCT_1, because it is the "primary key" of the SIZE table.  Trying to add a foreign key constraint to SIZE does not make any sense.

If you run SHOW INNODB STATUS you'll get some information indicating that you don't have the required index, however, logically, there is no reason to try and create that constraint.

You do however want to create the constraint on PRODUCT_1.  At that point, you will only be able to enter SIZE_ID values in PRODUCT_1 that already exist in SIZE, as that is a typical "lookup table" design.

Answer (score 1):

PRODUCT_1.SIZE_ID is in this example the foreign key, as it references the primary key of the other table, SIZE.
Therefore, the second ALTER TABLE statement is correct as it is a property of the PRODUCT_1 table.

Now, before you insert any rows into PRODUCT_1 table, you should make sure that table SIZE already has a record with the SIZE_ID referenced in your new row. If the database finds that you are trying to insert a row with a SIZE_ID that does not exist in the SIZE table, you violate the FOREIGN KEY constraint, and it will disallow you.